# Writing specific SaveAs as Google Extension

Tags: javascript, json, image, google-chrome-extension, save

I'm new to **Google Extension Conding**, and I have specific task to handle with:

Web page contains `<img>` between `<a></a>`.

- SRC of IMG's has randomed name with written size in the end of filename, like: `<img src="omnomnom_1024x768.jpg">.`
- `<a>` contains href sure.

I need my extension work this way:

1. When I move cursor above image I need to right click it, press "Save As Omnomnom".
2. Browser opens image under cursor but with another size (I see it like Chorme opens new tab with just rewrighting filename to, let's say, `"omnomnom_800x600.jpg"`)
3. After image DLed SaveAs dialog shows up, enter file name I want this file to be saved (ex. 1.jpg) and extension also generates a TXT file in the same directory with the same name as jpg (ex. 1.txt) and it must contain a "href" from `<a>` (holded an `<img src="omnomnom_1024x768.jpg">` between `<a>` tags).

Help please. I started with manifest.json, made 1st step, but stuck on 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of security, you can't download nor write a file from a page or extension.  Only the user can.
Extensions won't know what folder the user chose.  Chrome won't fire a script after save as dialog shows up.

If you must access the file system, you should look for a plugin to do it.  Flash is very popular in this matter.